# Google script for gmail api watch: No way to get message id for fresh emails?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

been using google script to trigger action when new mail comes in.

This is my `doPost` function

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var message = contents.message;
  var data = JSON.parse(Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(message.data)).getDataAsString());

  var historyId = data.historyId;

}
```

With this, I have access to historyId,... but to get the message object, or at least the message id of the mail, I will be needing to show the history. so:

```
 Gmail.Users.History.list("me", {"startHistoryId": historyId});
```

The expected result of the code above would be:

```
{ historyId: '######', history: [ { messages: [Object], id: '#####' } ] }
```

This is is true for mails that have threads or histories already.

BUT, this isn't the case for new mails. It only shows the historyId `{ historyId: '######' }`

My question is, is there really no way to get the message object for new mails? If not, how?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail.Users.Message.list() returns:

An email message.

JSON representation

{
"id": string,
"threadId": string,
"labelIds": [
string
],
"snippet": string,
"historyId": string,
"internalDate": string,
"payload": {
object (MessagePart)
},
"sizeEstimate": integer,
"raw": string
}

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the list. I want the specific message.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the history.list method is just returning the ID is explained in its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list)

> Returns history records **after the specified startHistoryId**. The supplied startHistoryId should be obtained from the historyId of a message, thread, or previous list response. **History IDs increase chronologically but are not contiguous with random gaps in between valid IDs.** (...) **If you receive no nextPageToken in the response, there are no updates to retrieve and you can store the returned historyId for a future request.**

This means that you will only get the messages *after* the specified History ID, so if you're tracking changes to the User's most recent History ID you will get blank responses.

To get the message objects you can use [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list) instead. And based on the quote above it seems that there's no easy way to get a list of all History IDs so they expect you to store the current ID when a change occurs and when you detect another change you can use the **stored** ID instead of the new one to get the most recent messages.